# How to fix "Failure - Unknown" while using Speculative Rules in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, prerender

Using javascript I insert next script

```html
<script type="speculativerules">
  {
    "prerender":[{
      "source":"list",
      "urls":["/cart"]
    }]
  }
</script>
```

My server correctly responds with the cart page and 200 HTTP status. However I see  an error "Failure - Unknown" in chrome devtools. I see no way how I can investigate this trouble further and make Speculation Rules work.

One thing I noticed: sometimes it helps to toggle Preload Pages tumbler in browser's settings.

[image]